# Identifying Differences in Rows using Groupby a Column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this reproducible dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B","C", "C", "D"), cost = c("0.5", "0.4", "0.7", "0.8", "0.5", "1.3", "1.3", "2.6"))
```

I'm trying to groupby the ID, to test if there are differences in the `cost` column and update a new column called `Test diff`

**Intermediate Output**

```
  ID cost Testdiff
1  A  0.5        Y
2  A  0.4        Y
3  B  0.7        Y
4  B  0.8        Y
5  B  0.5        Y
6  C  1.3        N
7  C  1.3        N
8  D  2.6        N
```

I'm looking at using a dplyr example to do this but I"m unsure if `match` is the correct function.

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Testdiff = ifelse(match(cost) == T, "Y", "N"))
```

Once that is completed, I want to keep the 1st row of the unique ID, giving me this output

```
  ID cost Testdiff
1  A  0.5        Y
2  B  0.7        Y
3  C  1.3        N
4  D  2.6        N
```

Comment: the type does not matter in my example. Just wanted to produce a reproducible example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(Testdiff = ifelse(all(cost == first(cost)), "N", "Y")) %>%
 filter(row_number() == 1)

  ID    cost  Testdiff
  <fct> <fct> <chr>   
1 A     0.5   Y       
2 B     0.7   Y       
3 C     1.3   N       
4 D     2.6   N
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(Testdiff = ifelse(all(cost == first(cost)), "N", "Y")) %>%
 top_n(1, wt = desc(row_number()))
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `n_distinct` and then `slice`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Testdiff = n_distinct(cost) > 1) %>%
  slice(1)

#    ID    cost  Testdiff
#   <fct> <fct> <lgl>   
#1   A     0.5   TRUE    
#2   B     0.7   TRUE    
#3   C     1.3   FALSE   
#4   D     2.6   FALSE
```

If you want output to be "Y"/"N" instead of TRUE/FALSE

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(Testdiff = ifelse(n_distinct(cost) > 1, "Y", "N")) %>%
 slice(1)
```

---

We could use `ave` and `aggregate` to solve it using base R

```
df$Testdiff <- ifelse(with(df, ave(cost, ID, FUN = function(x) 
                      length(unique(x)))) > 1, "Y", "N")

aggregate(.~ID, df, head, n = 1)


#  ID cost Testdiff
#1  A  0.5        Y
#2  B  0.7        Y
#3  C  1.3        N
#4  D  2.6        N
```

Comment: smart use of n_distinct!

Answer (score 2):

Since we have `dplyr` and `base R` already why not add in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(cost = cost[1], testdiff = uniqueN(cost) > 1), by = ID]

   ID cost testdiff
1:  A  0.5     TRUE
2:  B  0.7     TRUE
3:  C  1.3    FALSE
4:  D  2.6    FALSE
```